# Percentage within a group

Tags: sas

I am trying to compute the frequency of observation in a group. 
My dataset looks like:

```
Date Account C_group Age ...
1    152627    A     28
2    152627    B     28
1    163718    B     32
3    163628    D     12
4    163717    C     41
.
.
```

I would like to determine the percentage of accounts in the different groups.
Do you know how I could that?

Thanks

Comment: SAS Frequency Tables: https://libguides.library.kent.edu/SAS/Frequencies

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc. Does it returns the percentage? I wanted something that could count percentage of accounts within between C_group values

Comment: You'll have to better define the percentage.  Do you mean that group A is 20% of the total or that account 152627 is 11% of group A?

Comment: Yes, it would be great. But I would also to understand how to determine the percentage of A, B, C, and D.

Comment: PROC FREQ does percentages. Run it and check it yourself. You can get percents, row percents or column percents, as well as total or subtotal percents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you close to what you are looking for:

```
data dset   ;
input
freqgroup $
subgroup    ;
datalines ;
A 12
B 12
C 12
C 21
C 23
A 12
A 21
B 12
B 21
B 21
;
run;
proc sort data=dset;
by freqgroup;
run;
proc freq data=dset ;
    table freqgroup ;
run ;
proc freq data=dset ;
    by freqgroup    ;
    table subgroup  ;
run ;
```